# Overlapping Raincloud plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a simple raincloud plot using ggplot but I can't seem to prevent some plots from overlapping (others are a bit too close as well). I've tried the position = position_dodge options with a variety of arguments however nothing seems to work. My code is  below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks, Joe.

```
airquality %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = factor(Month), y = Temp, fill = factor(Month)))+
  # add half-violin from (ggdist} package
     ggdist::stat_halfeye(
         ## custom bandwidth
             adjust = 0.5,
         ## move geom to the right
             justification = -.2,
         ## remove slab interval
            .width = 0,
            point_colour = NA
) +
geom_boxplot(
          width = .2,
          ## remove outliers
             outlier.color = NA,
         alpha = 0.5
) +
       # Add dot plots from (ggdist} package
       ggdist::stat_dots(
           ## orientation to the left
              side = "left",
           ## move geom to the left
              justification = 1.1,
           ## adjust grouping (binning) of observations
              binwidth = .25
) +
       # Adjust theme
          scale_fill_tq() +
          theme_tq() +
       labs(
            title = "Raincloud Plot",
     subtitle = "Showing the Multi-Modal Distributions of Temperatures by Month",
            x    = "Month",
            y    = "Temperature Degrees F",
            fill = "Month"
) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `scale` parameter to prevent the overlap (like geom_ridgeline() from the ggridges package), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("ggdist")
library(ggdist)
library(tidyquant)

p <- airquality %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Month), y = Temp, fill = factor(Month)))+
  # add half-violin from (ggdist} package
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    ## custom bandwidth
    adjust = 0.5,
    ## move geom to the right
    justification = -.2,
    ## remove slab interval
    .width = 0,
    point_colour = NA,
    scale = 0.5 ##  <(**new parameter**)
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(
    width = .1, # <(**also changed this to suit**)
    ## remove outliers
    outlier.color = NA,
    alpha = 0.5
  ) +
  # Add dot plots from (ggdist} package
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    ## orientation to the left
    side = "left",
    ## move geom to the left
    justification = 1.1,
    ## adjust grouping (binning) of observations
    binwidth = .25,
  ) +
  # Adjust theme
  tidyquant::scale_fill_tq() +
  tidyquant::theme_tq() +
  labs(
    title = "Raincloud Plot",
    subtitle = "Showing the Multi-Modal Distributions of Temperatures by Month",
    x    = "Month",
    y    = "Temperature Degrees F",
    fill = "Month"
  ) +
  coord_flip()

ggsave(plot = p, filename = "raincloud.png",
       device = "png", height = 12,
       width = 12, units = "cm")
```

[image: image1.png]

Comment: This does work (thanks!) but it tends to flatten out the density plots. Is there a way to spread them w/o flattening the plots?

Comment: If you make the figure larger they won't look 'flattened'; if you use `ggsave()` to save your plot you can specify the height of the final image.

Comment: How would you enlarge the plot? By decreasing margins or some other way?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to 'lengthen' the plot. If you increase the height, you can also increase the scale (e.g. `height = 15` and `scale = 0.7`) and make the plots look less 'flattened'